# Server or "Workstation"

Tags: rendering

I know this question might not belong to this site, but I have a very important decision to take.
I want to buy a computer/server for rendering, but I am not sure about what would be the best...

The computer will have an intel processor with 6cores (12threas) and a rate of 3,3GHz per core.
It will also have 16GB of DDR4 RAM
I have to say that I have the power supply for this machine already at home.

The server will have four processors with 6cores each and a rate of 2,66GHz.
It will also have 32GB DDR2-RAM

What would be the better choice?

Comment: I suggest you take this question to Blenderartists.org. There is a forum for technical support in which what you're asking gets asked on a daily basis. Lots of information. The forum nature of that site is better suited for opinion based answers than this site.

Comment: The blender.org has a page dedicated to the suggested hardware specs: https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Comment: This answer might be of help. [4 fast cores or 6 slower ones?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21810/2217)